# Cannot interpolate dataframe even if most of the data is filled

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to interpolate the NaN in my DataFrame using `interpolate()` method. However, the method failed with error :

> Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.

Here's the code:

```
try:
    df3.interpolate(method='index', inplace=True)
    processor._arma(df3['TCA'])
except Exception, e:
    sys.stderr.write('%s: [%s] %s\n' % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), nid3, e))
    sys.stderr.write('%s: [%s] len=%d\n' % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), nid3, len(df3.index)))
    sys.stderr.write('%s: [%s] %s\n' % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), nid3, df3.to_string()))
```

This is strange, because most of the data is already filled, as you can see in **log 1** or **log 2**. The length of the dataframe is 20, as all the data shown below. Even each cell is filled, I still can't use interpolate method. BTW, `df3` is a **global** value, I'm not sure if it would be a problem.

---

**log 1**

```
2016-01-21 22:06:11: [ESIG_node_003_400585511] Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.
2016-01-21 22:06:11: [ESIG_node_003_400585511] len=20
2016-01-21 22:06:11: [ESIG_node_003_400585511]
                     TCA TCB TCC
2016-01-21 20:06:22  19  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:23  19  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:24  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:25  18  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:26  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:27  19  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:28  19  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:29  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:30  18  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:31  19  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:32  18  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:33  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:34  19  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:35  18  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:36  19  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:37  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:38  18  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:39  19  18  18
2016-01-21 20:06:40  18  17  18
2016-01-21 20:06:41  18  18  18
```

**log 2**

```
2016-01-21 22:06:14: [ESIG_node_003_400585511] Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.
2016-01-21 22:06:14: [ESIG_node_003_400585511] len=20
2016-01-21 22:06:14: [ESIG_node_003_400585511]
                      TCA  TCB  TCC
2016-01-21 20:06:33   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:34   19   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:35   18   17   18
2016-01-21 20:06:36   19   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:37   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:38   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:39   19   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:40   18   17   18
2016-01-21 20:06:41   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:42  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-01-21 20:06:43  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-01-21 20:06:44  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-01-21 20:06:45  NaN  NaN  NaN
2016-01-21 20:06:46   19   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:47   18   17   18
2016-01-21 20:06:48   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:49   19   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:50   18   17   18
2016-01-21 20:06:51   18   18   18
2016-01-21 20:06:52   19   17   18
```

Comment: Are you sure that `method=index` can work on the date-time values in the first column?

Comment: I've tried `method='index'`, `method='time'` or without method. None of them works.

Comment: But `method=time` won't likely work on the other columns. Have you tried column by column, to see which works and which doesn't?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check that your DataFrame has *numeric dtypes*, not `object` dtypes.  The
`TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs` can occur if the DataFrame
contains columns of `object` dtype. For example, if

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.array([1,np.nan,30], dtype='O')}, 
                  index=['2016-01-21 20:06:22', '2016-01-21 20:06:23', 
                         '2016-01-21 20:06:24'])
```

then `df.interpolate()` raises the TypeError.

To check if your DataFrame has columns with object dtype, look at `df3.dtypes`:

```
In [92]: df.dtypes
Out[92]: 
A    object
dtype: object
```

To fix the problem, you need to ensure the DataFrame has numeric columns with
native NumPy dtypes. Obviously, it would be best to build the DataFrame
correctly from the very beginning. So the best solution depends on how you are
building the DataFrame.

A less appealing patch-up fix would be to use `pd.to_numeric` to convert the object arrays to numeric arrays after-the-fact:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

With `errors='coerce'`, any value that could not be converted to a number is converted to NaN. After calling `pd.to_numeric` on each column, notice that the dtype is now `float64`:

```
In [94]: df.dtypes
Out[94]: 
A    float64
dtype: object
```

Once the DataFrame has numeric dtypes, and the DataFrame has a DatetimeIndex, then `df.interpolate(method='time')` will work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.array([1,np.nan,30], dtype='O')}, 
                  index=['2016-01-21 20:06:22', '2016-01-21 20:06:23', 
                         '2016-01-21 20:06:24'])

for col in df:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df = df.interpolate(method='time')
print(df)
```

yields

```
                        A
2016-01-21 20:06:22   1.0
2016-01-21 20:06:23  15.5
2016-01-21 20:06:24  30.0
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful for understanding where the problem comes from and how to resolve. The 3 columns do have type `object` as you said. For the rest, I need to check it tomorrow. So your answer would be accepted later. Thx a lot !!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what needs to be done when having both float64 and int64 data types? I used the code with the older version of Pandas and it used to work but ever since updating the Pandas it is not working anymore @unutbu

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, recreated the dataframe with definition of dtype as float (e.g. `dtype='float32'`). it fixed.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = df.values, columns= cols, dtype='float32')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i made this code it modifies the Dataframe interpolating all values using numpy, you can put an if for selecting those u dont want to interpolate.

X is a DataFrame.

```
for i in X:
    
     X[i]=(parseArg(X[i]))

def nan_helper(y):

    y=np.array(y)

    return np.isnan(y), lambda z: z.nonzero()[0]

def parseArg(y):

    y=np.array(y)
    nans, i= nan_helper(y)
    y[nans]= np.interp(i(nans), i(~nans), y[~nans])
    y=y.ravel()
    
    return y
```